# Is it bad to hotlink jQuery from jquery.com?

Tags: jquery, cdn, hotlinking

This will probably get a pretty nasty response, but my server isn't the fastest at the moment, and my site loads much faster if I hotlink from the jQuery homepage so they server the content. Is this bad to do? Does jQuery eventually remove those js files from their page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Better hotlink it from [Google API libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html).

Very big advantages:

- Google is fast and highly available
- Separate hosts, allows the client to load JQuery simultaneously with your pages and images (browsers support only a limited number of connections per host)
- Probably even faster still, because many websites use it, so this Google version is probably in your visitor's cache anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using their [official CDNs?](https://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn) ([old link](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery)) A lot of people do.

I'm not sure why everyone is so quick to say Google. The above link says very specifically that you can hotlink to the jQuery CDN:

> jQuery CDN (via Media Temple)
>
> http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
> Minified version
>
> http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js
> Source version

Answer (score 2):

Instead use [Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery). That is what it was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

if it is bad I haven't heard about it. However you can **use a CDN for better performance** probably. Google and Microsoft also serve jQuery through their CDN for free.

**cdnjs:**
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

**Google's CDN:**
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#Libraries

**jQuery's CDN:**
http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

**MS's CDN:**
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#Third-Party_Files_on_the_CDN_14

Comment: Ironically I visited a Microsoft site today and got a warning that jQuery was being served from jQuery's CDN...

Comment: Ahh, I never noticed that before. I see that they list that right above there.

Comment: Actually looking at it further it says the libraries come from someone else, not that its hosted somewhere else. I think they're saying that MS doesn't control jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is not intended for loading from the URL, I would avoid it.

However, Google provides hosted versions:

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) and link it from there : )

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google's hosted versions:

http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it is bad. For your site - it will run slower. For their site - imagine what happens if everyone used it!

Comment: I have to disagree with "your site .. will run slower". Retrieving it from a domain other than yours allows more parallel downloads and will most likely speed things up. Not to mention the fact that the OP specifically says that there server isn't fast. jQuerys one is almost certainly faster. Oh and there's the increased likelihood of a cache hit with a CDN version too.

Comment: Again, jQuery's site specifically says that you can hotlink to jQ from their CDN.