# $ or jQuery is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    console.log($);
    console.log(jQuery);
</script>
```

I get a message that `$` or `jQuery` is undefined: what’s wrong?

It’s just an empty index.html, with no other code.

Comment: If you want a hosted version of jQuery you might want to use a [CDN version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514072/is-it-bad-to-hotlink-jquery-from-jquery-com).

Comment: @tadman use googles url for it.

Comment: @tadman That IS a CDN version. MaxCDN

Comment: @KevinB Right you are. I thought that was the download link pasted in there.

Comment: And, by using MaxCDN, it won't be blocked by companies (or countries) that block google-related traffic.

Comment: You also might want to search Stack Overflow for that error: [https://www.google.com/#q=%22%24%22+or+jQuery+is+undefined+site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/#q=%22%24%22+or+jQuery+is+undefined+site:stackoverflow.com). There's a few hits. (I don't feel the close reason was appropriate on your question given the breadth of answers to similar past problems. If you get closed again as a duplicate, then that is "shame on you").

Answer (score 25):

You used the `href` attribute to include the script to the file.

`href` is an invalid attribute for `<script></script>` tags. Use `src` instead...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an error in your declaration.
You should use

```
<script src="...">
```

instead of

```
<script href="">.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    console.log($);
    console.log(jQuery);
</script>
```

Always try to use js files on your local machine.